# Crear un Json con Modelos

Tags: json, array, flutter, dart

Se tiene 2 modelos, el cual el 1er modelo tiene una lista del 2do modelo, lo que se desea es poder tener un Json como el siguiente ejemplo:

```html
{
  "valor": 2,
  "opcion":"B",
  "items":[
    {"nombre": juan, "edad": 4},
    {"nombre": juana, "edad": 41} 
  ]
  
  
}
```

Los modelos son:

```html
class ArticulosCanasta {
  int idArticulo;
  int cantidad;
  String instrucciones;
  List<DetalleCanasta> detalles_Articulos = [];
  ArticulosCanasta(
      {this.idArticulo,
      this.cantidad,
      this.instrucciones,
      this.detalles_Articulos});

   
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['idArticulo'] = this.idArticulo;
    data['cantidad'] = this.cantidad;
    data['instrucciones'] = this.instrucciones;

    if (this.detalles_Articulos != null) {
      data['detalles_Articulos'] = this.detalles_Articulos.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  } 


}

class DetalleCanasta {
  int idDetalle;
  int idOpcion;
  int idTipo;
  DetalleCanasta({this.idDetalle, this.idOpcion, this.idTipo});
 
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['idDetalle'] = this.idDetalle;
    data['idOpcion'] = this.idOpcion;
    data['idTipo'] = this.idTipo;

    return data;
  }
}
```

El resto del codigo seria instanciar e insertar valores  primero un objeto, despues se ingresaria este objeto al siguiente objeto, pero al momento de usar el metodo **add(objeto)** me da un error, diciendo que no es del mismo tipo, y por ultimo, como puedo crear este objeto un Json como el del ejemplo del inicio del post.

```html
DetalleCanasta detalle_canasta = new DetalleCanasta(
    idDetalle :12,
    idOpcion : 23,
    idTipo : 31,

  );
 

  DetalleCanasta detalle_canasta2 = new DetalleCanasta(
    idDetalle :1,
    idOpcion : 2,
    idTipo : 3,

  );
 

  ArticulosCanasta articulo_canasta = new ArticulosCanasta();

  articulo_canasta.idArticulo = 1;
  articulo_canasta.cantidad = 2;
  articulo_canasta.instrucciones = "pepe";
  //Error aqui
articulo_canasta.detalles_Articulos.add(detalle_canasta2);
```

Comment: Quieres un método que te genere el json que tienes como ejemplo al inicio  apartir de un modelo ?
Por que parece que ya tienes algo parecido en tu modelo llamado toJson, dicho método te genera algún error ?

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, Ya se solvento el problema.

Comment: No hay problema, sube el como resolviste el problema para que otros sepan darle solución a problemas similares o cierra tu pregunta, Saludos.